# How can I apply :special-members: to just one class inside an automodule directive?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc, sphinx-napoleon, double-underscore

I am putting together Sphinx-driven (v1.3.1) documentation for a Python 2.7 project using `autodoc` and `napoleon`.  Inside one module, which I'd like to document with a single `automodule::` directive, I have a specific class to which I want to apply the `:special-members:` flag.  Flagging the `automodule::` with `:special-members:` shows the specials for *everything* in the module, and that's no good.

How can I do this?

Adding an `autoclass::` directive flagged with `:special-members:` still leaves the "non-specialized" documentation there as part of the `automodule::` content, resulting in duplicated content.

I suppose I could explicitly type out all of the classes in the module except my specials-targeted one in a `:members:` instruction on the `automodule::`, but then I'd have to remember to update that list every time I added or removed a class to the module.

Comment: hmmm, its a shame b/c it looks like there is an argument on `autoclass::` where you can specify special members to doc, but the `automodule::` doesn't have one to specify classes that get the special treatment .... might be worth it do dig into the source depending on how much time you want to put in  https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/master/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py

Comment: Mmph. Tempting, but probably not worth doing for this (for now) one-off situation.  Is there maybe a flag I can stick into the docstring to trigger special-members for the one class?

Comment: might be easier to write a python script that inspects the module and then explicitly writes out all the classes as you describe in the last paragraph of your question.

Comment: @Gabriel <nod>, if I need to do it a lot I'll definitely consider automation like that, or even forking sphinx and fiddling. For now, I just moved the docstrings of the special members over to raw rST in the parent class docstring.  Looks just how I want. There's one more class I know of in the project where I'll have to do it again, but I think that's it. Not too bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this is excluding the members that you want different options applied to  in `automodule`. Afterwards include them with their own directive, setting the particular options you want on that directive.

The following example excludes `ClassB` from the `automodule` directive. Afterwards `ClassB` is included in the context of the `automodule` with its own `autoclass` directive. Under the `:special-members:` option set only the members you want shown.

[image]

Corresponding `.rst` file:

```
selective module
================

.. automodule:: selective
    :members:
    :exclude-members: ClassB

    .. autoclass:: ClassB
        :special-members: __init__, __special_func_two__
```

Corresponding `.py` file:

```py
"""This modules docstring."""


class ClassA:
    """ClassA docstring."""

    def __special_func_one__(self, two):
        """Special method docstring."""
        self.two = two

    def __init__(self, one):
        """Special method docstring."""
        self.one = one


class ClassB:
    """ClassB docstring."""

    def __special_func_two__(self, two):
        """Special method docstring."""
        self.two = two

    def __special_func_three__(self, three):
        """Special method docstring."""
        self.three = three

    def __init__(self, one):
        """Special method docstring."""
        self.one = one
```

This minimizes the number of exceptions you have to type because default rules still apply normally to the remaining members of the module, except when you indicate otherwise. In most IDEs this solution will also refactor changes made to the Python source code.

For the exact solution shown `special-members` and `private-members` were not included in `autodoc_default_options` inside `conf.py`. The relevant sphinx.ext.napoleon setting was set to `napoleon_include_special_with_doc = False`. However, the individual directive settings would still take precedence over the former general configurations.

Comment: Didn't realize you could put additional markup inside an `.. autoxyz::` directive. Perfect--thanks!